# Need assistance with implementing AJAX add to cart in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a WooCommerce website and trying to implement AJAX add to cart functionality, from the shop page, where i list all the products and customers have to select ttype of product and quantity before hitting the add to cart. I want to allow users to add products to their carts without the page reloading, and whitout the need of opening of the single poduct page. I'm can add the product to the cart, based on their slection, each prodcut has three attributes which creates three different products, but I am having trouble to add also the quantity of the items, from the request pannel i can see i send the right amount but then only one item is added.

Here is the code I have implemented in my child theme's functions.php and

```
    <?php
/**
 * [p. name] engine room
 *
 * @package [p. name]
 */

// ...

require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/filter-shop.php';

function enable_cors() {
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
}
add_action('init', 'enable_cors');

function add_quick_filter_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('filter-shop', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/filter-shop.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

    // Localize script and pass necessary parameters
    wp_localize_script('filter-shop', 'wc_quick_filter_params', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    ));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_quick_filter_scripts');

function enqueue_quick_add_to_cart_script() {
    if (is_shop()) {
        // Enqueue the quick-add.js script from the child theme directory
        wp_enqueue_script('quick-add-to-cart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/quick-add.js', array('jquery', 'wc-add-to-cart'), '1.0', true);

        // Localize script and pass necessary parameters
        wp_localize_script('quick-add-to-cart', 'wc_quick_add_params', array(
            'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
            'nonce' => wp_create_nonce('quick_add_to_cart')
        ));
    }
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_quick_add_to_cart_script');

function your_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue the slider script from the child theme directory
    wp_enqueue_script('slider-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/slider.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'your_theme_enqueue_scripts');

// ...

function quick_add_to_cart() {
    // Verify the AJAX request
    check_ajax_referer('quick_add_to_cart', 'nonce');

    // Get the product ID from the AJAX request
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

    // Add the product to the cart
    $result = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id);

    if ($result) {
        // Product added successfully
        $response = array(
            'success' => true,
            'message' => __('Product added to cart', '[p. name]')
        );
    } else {
        // Failed to add product to cart
        $response = array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => __('Failed to add product to cart', '[p. name]')
        );
    }

    wp_send_json($response);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_quick_add_to_cart', 'quick_add_to_cart');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_quick_add_to_cart', 'quick_add_to_cart');

function enqueue_slick_library() {
    wp_enqueue_style('slick-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/slick/slick.css');
    wp_enqueue_script('slick-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/slick/slick.min.js', array('jquery'), '1.9.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_slick_library');

function custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold( $qty, $product ) { 
    return 100;
}        
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'custom_wc_ajax_variation_threshold', 100, 2 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function quantity_inputs_for_loop_ajax_add_to_cart( $html, $product ) {
    if ( $product && $product->is_type( 'simple' ) && $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() && ! $product->is_sold_individually() ) {
        // Get the necessary classes
        $class = implode( ' ', array_filter( array(
            'button',
            'product_type_' . $product->get_type(),
            $product->is_purchasable() && $product->is_in_stock() ? 'add_to_cart_button' : '',
            $product->supports( 'ajax_add_to_cart' ) ? 'ajax_add_to_cart' : '',
        ) ) );

        // Adding embeding <form> tag and the quantity field
        $html = sprintf( '%s%s<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>%s',
        '<form class="cart">',
        woocommerce_quantity_input( array(), $product, false ),
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() ),
        '</form>'
        );
    }
    return $html;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer' , 'archives_quantity_fields_script' );

function archives_quantity_fields_script(){
    //if( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ): ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
        $( document ).on( 'change', '.quantity .qty', function() {
            $( this ).parent( '.quantity' ).next( '.add_to_cart_button' ).attr( 'data-quantity', $( this ).val() );
            //alert("Changed");
        });
    });
        
        jQuery(function($) {
            // Update quantity on 'a.button' in 'data-quantity' attribute (for ajax) 
            $(".add_to_cart_button.product_type_simple").on('click', function() {
                var $button = $(this);
                $button.data('quantity', $button.parent().find('input.qty').val());
            });
            // remove old "view cart" text, only need latest one thanks!
            $(document.body).on("adding_to_cart", function() {
                $("a.added_to_cart").remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php //endif;
}
?>
```

this is the quick-add.js function that handle the ajax:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('form.variations_form').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      var $form = $(this);
      var $submitButton = $form.find('button[type="submit"]');
  
      // Disable the submit button to prevent multiple submissions
      $submitButton.prop('disabled', true);
  
      // Retrieve selected attributes
      var data = $form.serializeArray().reduce(function(obj, item) {
        obj[item.name] = item.value;
        return obj;
      }, {});
  
      // Retrieve the product variations data
      var variationsData = $form.data('product_variations');
  
      console.log('variationsData:', variationsData); // Output variationsData to the console
  
      if (variationsData) {
        var variations = variationsData; // Assign variationsData directly to variations
  
        // Find the matching variation
        var matchingVariation = variations.find(function(variation) {
          for (var attr in variation.attributes) {
            if (
              variation.attributes.hasOwnProperty(attr) &&
              variation.attributes[attr] !== data[attr]
            ) {
              return false;
            }
          }
          return true;
        });
  
        if (matchingVariation) {
          // Get the child variation ID
          var childVariationID = matchingVariation.variation_id;
  
          // Retrieve the selected quantity for this variation
          // Retrieve the selected quantity for this variation
          var quantityInput = $form.find('input[name^="quantity"]');
          var quantity = parseInt(quantityInput.val(), 10) || 1;
          // Add the product to the cart
          var addToCartData = {
            action: 'quick_add_to_cart',
            product_id: childVariationID,
            quantity: quantity,
            nonce: wc_quick_add_params.nonce
          };
  
          console.log('addToCartData:', addToCartData); // Output addToCartData to the console
  
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: wc_quick_add_params.ajax_url,
            data: addToCartData,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
              if (response && response.success) {
                // Product added successfully, handle the response
                console.log(response.message);
  
                // Trigger cart update
                $form.trigger('wc_cart_button_updated');
                $(document.body).trigger('wc_fragment_refresh');
  
                // Insert the success message only if it doesn't exist already
                if ($form.prev('.woocommerce-message').length === 0) {
                  var message = response.message;
                  var $messageContainer = $('<div class="woocommerce-message" role="alert"></div>');
                  $messageContainer.html(message);
                  $form.before($messageContainer);
                }
              } else {
                // Error occurred, display the error message
                console.log(response.message);
                alert(response.message);
              }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              // Error occurred, display the error message
              console.log(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
              alert(textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            },
            complete: function() {
              // Re-enable the submit button
              $submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
            }
          });
        } else {
          // No matching variation found
          console.log('No matching variation found');
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

and finally the custom page php that i use on the content-product.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying product content in the loop.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/content-product.php
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

global $product;

// Ensure visibility.
if (empty($product) || !$product->is_visible()) {
    return;
}

// Check if the product is on sale.
$is_on_sale = $product->is_on_sale();

// Start the product loop item.
?>

<li <?php wc_product_class('product', $product); ?>>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url($product->get_permalink()); ?>" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
        <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_show_product_loop_sale_flash - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail - 10
         */
        do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title');
        ?>

        <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title"><?php echo esc_html($product->get_name()); ?></h2>

    </a>

    <?php if ($product->is_type('variable')) : ?>
        <?php
        $variation_data = $product->get_variation_attributes();
        $available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

        if (!empty($available_variations)) :
            wp_enqueue_script('ajax-add-to-cart', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/quick-add.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        ?>
            <form class="variations_form cart" action="<?php echo esc_url(apply_filters('woocommerce_add_to_cart_form_action', $product->get_permalink())); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="<?php echo absint($product->get_id()); ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(wp_json_encode($available_variations)); ?>">
                <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_variations_form'); ?>

                <?php foreach ($variation_data as $attribute_name => $options) : ?>
                    <div class="variation">
                        <label for="<?php echo esc_attr(sanitize_title($attribute_name)); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label($attribute_name); ?></label>
                        <?php
                        wc_dropdown_variation_attribute_options(
                            array(
                                'options' => $options,
                                'attribute' => $attribute_name,
                                'product' => $product,
                                'show_option_none' => __('Select', 'woocommerce'),
                            )
                        );
                        
                        ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                <div class="single_variation_wrap">
                    <?php
                    /**
                     * Hook: woocommerce_before_single_variation.
                     */
                    do_action('woocommerce_before_single_variation');

                    /**
                     * Hook: woocommerce_single_variation. Used to output the cart button and placeholder for variation data.
                     *
                     * @since 2.4.0
                     * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation - 10 Empty div for variation data.
                     * @hooked woocommerce_single_variation_add_to_cart_button - 20 Qty and cart button.
                     */
                    do_action('woocommerce_single_variation');

                    /**
                     * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_variation.
                     */
                    do_action('woocommerce_after_single_variation');
                    ?>
                </div>

                <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_variations_form'); ?>
                
            </form>
        <?php else : ?>
            <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php echo esc_html(apply_filters('woocommerce_out_of_stock_message', __('This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce'))); ?></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <?php
        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart - 10
         */
        do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item');
        ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```

I would appreciate any help in identifying what might be causing the issue and how I can adjust the code to achieve the desired AJAX add to cart functionality in WooCommerce. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure the solution I propose will work as is written (might need some value checks / default etc), but I am quite confident about where the problem comes from: you send the quantity properly, but you don't process it in the ajax action function. If the second parameter of `add_to_cart` is missing, it is assumed `1`.

You should be able to get it from `POST` data:

```
function quick_add_to_cart() {
    // Verify the AJAX request
    check_ajax_referer('quick_add_to_cart', 'nonce');

    // Get the product ID from the AJAX request
    $product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

    // Get the quantity from the AJAX request
    $quantity= $_POST['quantity'];

    // Add the product to the cart
    $result = WC()->cart->add_to_cart($product_id, $quantity);

    if ($result) {
        // Product added successfully
        $response = array(
            'success' => true,
            'message' => __('Product added to cart', '[p. name]')
        );
    } else {
        // Failed to add product to cart
        $response = array(
            'success' => false,
            'message' => __('Failed to add product to cart', '[p. name]')
        );
    }

    wp_send_json($response);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to add it to my functions, worked Thank you for taking the time and look at it

Comment: Glad to help, good luck for the rest! Your code is clean and well organized so it wasn't so hard to spot